# Use USB to synchronize large directory between two disconnected servers

Tags: files, synchronization

I'd like to synchronize a large directory between two disconnected servers with a USB device that's too small to hold the entire directory.
Each server has a majority of the data and the changed files are
small enough to fit on my USB device.

Is there a tool I can use to do the following steps?

1. Device B: Compute and store hashes from directory D to the usb device
2. Device A: Compute and compare hashes. Add unsynchronized files to the usb device and make note of the deleted files.
3. Device B: Sync changes from usb device to D, now having the same version as Device A.

To my knowledge, tools like rsync, rdiff-backup, and unison don't support this,
so my best solution to this would be to write a few simple scripts to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to get a cross-over cable and connect the two machines. :) But if you absolutely must do it with a flash memory and some duct tape, you could do it like this:

On the **destination** machine:

- `find /some/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha1sum -b | sort >dst.txt`
- copy the `dst.txt` file to the **source** machine

On the **source** machine:

- `find /some/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha1sum -b | sort >src.txt`
- `comm -23 src.txt dst.txt | cut -b 43- | (cd /some/dir; tar cJvf - --files-from -) | split -b 3500MB -d`
- copy the `x*` files one by one to the **destination** machine
- `rm -f x* src.txt dst.txt`

On the **destination** machine again:

- `cat $( ls -1 x* | sort ) | (cd /some/dir; tar xJvpf -)`
- `rm -f x*`

How is this supposed to work:

- the `dst.txt` and `src.txt` files contain SHA-1 sums of the files on the two machines
- `comm -23 src.txt dst.txt` selects the files that either exist only on the **source** machine, or exist on both but are different
- `cut -b 43-` keeps only the filenames; this is the list of files that need to be copied
- `cd /some/dir` changes `CWD` to the source directory
- `tar cJvpf - --files-from -` makes an archive of the bunch; `--files-from -` reads the list of files to archive from `stdin`, `f -` tells `tar` to write the archive to `stdout`, `J` means to compress the archive with `xz`, and `v` makes `tar` print the list of files it archives to `stderr`
- `split -b 3500MB -d` splits the archive in chunks of 3500MB (I'm assuming you have a 4GB flash memory, and the data won't fit all in a single run; you might not need to do this at all)
- `cat $( ls -1 x* | sort )` concatenates the `x*` files; `sort` is there to make sure it does that in the right order
- `cd /some/dir` changes `CWD` to the destination directory
- `tar xJvpf -` saves the files; `J` means decompress with `xz`, `p` means restore permissions, `v` makes the operation verbose, and `f -` tells `tar` to read the archive from `stdin`.

Finally, the @Stéphane Chazelas disclaimer: this assumes that (1) filenames on either machine don't contain newlines, and (2) the directories to mirror are not too deep (there's a limit to the maximum path length of files in `tar` archives, and it isn't very high - 200 characters IIRC).

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I'm thinking. I overlooked that this can be done in 3 steps instead of 4 (updated my question). For xargs, I'll use `--max-procs` [(docs)](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Controlling-Parallelism.html) to speed up the hashing. I'll also use a similar strategy to remove files. I'm leaving this question open for a few more hours to see if somebody has another solution.

Comment: @Brandon Amos: Unless the files you want to mirror are already cached, hashing is likely to be I/O bound, not CPU bound.  If that's the case, increasing concurrency more than, say, 2 simultaneous processes is likely to increase the total time, rather than decrease it.  FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

Can `tar` in combination with the `-N | --newer | --after` parameter help you?. It allows you to backup all the files which are modified since the specified date.

If you create a file list (using `find` for example) before each run, you can compare the files to see which files are removed. Using that output you can remove the extra files from the destination server.